# Loading a CSS 'theme' before the viewable page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have what I hope to be a fairly simple question. To start off I'll say that I'm using jQuery and jscookie.

I have 2 different CSS files, a light theme and a dark theme. Initially in the `<head>` I have this `<link>` tag:

```
<link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" href="css/dark.css" />
```

This loads the dark theme by default.

I have a situation where the user can toggle the theme with a button, which also updates a cookie stating their theme preference. Since the dark theme is the default, we only need to check if the user has the 'light' theme as their preference. I have some javascript that runs in the head, just underneath the link:

```
if(theme_preference == 'light') { // theme_preference is the value of the cookie
    jQuery('#theme').attr('href', 'css/light.css');
}
```

50% of the time this code works and the theme is changed before any of the page content is loaded, but the other 50% of the time the page loads before (I assume?) the jQuery runs, so the user will visually see the page flick from dark to light theme.

What event/other thing do I need to harness to make sure that this code executes and updates the `<link>` href *before* the user sees any of the screen?

Thanks very much in advance to anyone who can point me in the right direction!

Comment: What programming languages do you use in your complete code? If you also use for instance PHP to generate the HTML page, you could get PHP to make the decision about the theme by reading the cookie. For the rest I don't see how you are able to prevent what you currently get.

Comment: I am using PHP, yes. How would I read a cookie set by jscookie from PHP?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp there it states how you can read cookies, cookies are browser specific, not language specific. You can just read them. If your page loads (and it's a PHP file) you can just get the PHP file to read what the cookie contains and set it upon generating the HTML accordingly.

Comment: Oh I see! I didn't realise it was browser rather than language specific! It works! If you post that comment I will accept it as the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that (as we discussed in the comments) you use PHP as well.
You can just make PHP read the cookie and use that variable. Since PHP is processed before the website is loaded by your browser, it will set the correct configuration. Cookies are browser specific, not programming language specific. Here's how to do it in PHP: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp